# Display Progressive JPEG on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, image, jpeg

Is it possible to make IE start displaying Progressive JPEG before the image has been completely downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer on Windows does not support rendering of Progressive JPEG.
However, Internet Explorer on Mac OS X does implement and support it. It's also indicated in the [Comparison of Web Browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 4):

Nope, Microsoft seems to not value the benefits of progressive JPEG in Internet Explorer.