# Is there any benefit to use Progressive image display for JPG, Gif and PNG?

Tags: css, xhtml, cross-browser

Is there any benefit to use Progressive image display, these days, for JPG, Gif and PNG?

Should we use progressive image in both condition as a `<img>` and in css `background`?

Does all mainstream **desktop and mobile browsers** support progressive display?

mobiles doesn't have much speed? so is it really usefful for mibile phone

Answer (score 1):

Progressive display is useful where there is a slow data link.  It allows the person viewing the image to get an idea of what it contains with only a little bit of it transmitted.  They might choose to abort transmission if it isn't of interest.

I don't know of any important browsers which don't support progressive display.

Comment: u mean IE,6,7 and 8 supports it.

Comment: No—I mean Firefox, SeaMonkey, Chrome, Netscape, Opera, and the last two versions of MSIE.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's useful for people on dialup, otherwise I don't think it matters.
2. Yes, they support it.

Answer (score 0):

- Immediate, progressive image display
- Lossless image transfer possible
- Full true color (no dithering reducing image quality)
- No blocking and no color falsity on highly compressed images

Progressive display. Gives quickly a good preview for huge depth 3D images or with slow connection.

All the browsers do support this.

Comment: but see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345791/display-progressive-jpeg-on-ie

Answer (score 0):

1) Of course - If you are interested in every millisecond that counts in page speed optimization.

> The biggest advantage of using progressive browser display images is that the user can view a low quality version of the image very quickly, with gradual improvement as one waits longer. This way, the user will have access faster to the existing information, review images without waiting for the complete download of resources and focus on what he is interested on.

More info here: http://wpy.me/blog/12-progressive-browser-display-images

2) Yes you shouldn't worry about that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28graphics%29#JPEG_support